# How do I get clean boot after fresh side by side install?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, grubrescue, error-handling

I was running Windows 7 Pro (32 bit) OS on my Dell Dimension 9100. I attempted to load (side by side) Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop.  The install appeared to work properly into a 19 GB partition.  When completed, the restart (reboot) brought up the following message.

```
error: no such device: e4958c47-7613-4ca4-82d6-b80ffc2b2148
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Even after removing the Ubuntu with OS-Uninstaller, the above message returns on every boot.

So how do I get back to a Windows 7 boot?

Comment: follow the method on this page [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you will need a windows disc, start windows installer via the boot menu, and then run boot repair.

I don't know if something like Ultimate boot cd or system rescue cd will work as I've never had a need to use them.

BTW, its called dual boot not side-by-side. Apparently, it looks like you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: improve your answer sir, if the person is newbee he will not understand your shorthand method. anyways this question is duplicate already, the link I gave is thorough with images to explain

Comment: The Windows Installation disk was able to get the MBR fixed.  All is well now.  Yes, I am a newbee.  But having gone through this problem, I think I will try again to "dual boot" load 14.04, since I now know how to get the normal boot back.